# How can I get live data from an API using HTTP.Get

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http

Using
**ANGULAR**

I would like http.get to frequently pull data from an API, and can't find a viable solution. The API is providing minute by minute traffic data, and I would like Angular to reflect the updates.

At the moment i am using **interval** from **rxjs** to refresh the Get request, but that's crashing the browser. This turns out, is not a suitable way do get this done. It is memory intensive.

```
interval(3000).subscribe(x => { http.get('api.link')});
```

What solution is there that I could get this done conservatively ?

Comment: How much data typically comes back from the request? What are you doing with it afterwards? What does the stack trace/error messages look like when this “*crash*” occurs?

Comment: Maybe also check if the API provides a websocket endpoint to listen to.

Comment: They unfortunately don't.

Comment: They may have rate limiting. If it provides minute by minute update, you should make your interval 60,000 ms or so

Answer (score 1):

i handle these situations with following code:

```
interval(3000).pipe(
  map(() => this.http.get('apiUrl')),
  mergeMap(x => x)
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the request sometimes takes more than 3 sec.

You need to use concatMap to ensure that the next request will only be fired after the current one is completed, ensuring that requests do not overlap

```
interval(3000).pipe(
      concatMap(() => this.http.get('api.link'))
    ).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        // Handle the incoming data
      },
      error: (error) => {
        // Handle any error
      }
    });
  }
```